# updating the value of attribute in database after clicking the positive button of the alertbox

Tags: java, android, database, android-alertdialog

I am showing an alert dialogue box on my app, and what I want is as soon as I click the positive button of the alert box it should change the value of an attribute in my database, I know how to do it in the php side but I am not getting how to do it in android side, if someone can help please? 
Here is the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

            builder1.setMessage(result);
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "accept", // this is the button that would change the value of attribute in the database
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            ctx.startActivity(new Intent(ctx, emergency.class));
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    "reject",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
        }
```

Comment: get the readable object of your database and execute the query on it

Comment: can you tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

When the button is clicked, you can setup an `HTTP GET` request to call your php file on the server with the desired GET parameters. Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html), this is one way of creating a request.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use Volley library to do it.

php code:

```
  <?php

    $edit_id=$_GET['edit_id'];
$vallue=$_GET['value'];




    require_once 'config.php';
    mysql_set_charset('utf8');
    mysql_query("update tbl set `value`='{$value}' where `edit_id`='{$edit_id}'");
    if(mysql_affected_rows()==1)
    {
        echo 'updated';
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
    }


    mysql_close();
    ?>
```

Your Alert Builder code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);

            builder1.setMessage(result);
            builder1.setCancelable(true);

            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "accept", // this is the button that would change the value of attribute in the database
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                 changeValue("your domain.php?edit_id="+edit_id+"&value="+value);
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            builder1.setNegativeButton(
                    "reject",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
        }
```

Not come to volley part:

```
    public void changeValue(String url)
    {
        final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
//                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());


                try{


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                }catch(Exception ex){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


                pDialog.hide();

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());





                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        //Adding request to request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(strReq);
    }
```

Now you can use it to edit the entry in database

Comment: hey thank you abhinaw, but am already using asyncTask and have done so much, can you tell me the other way around?